# rxjs: Can I unsubscribe without getting the subscription from outside?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Say I have this event coming through:

```
events
    .pipe(filter(data => data === MessageType.INIT))
    .subscribe(() => doSomething())
```

In order to unsubscribe to this, I would need to

```
const sub = events
    .pipe(filter(data => data === MessageType.INIT))
    .subscribe(() => {
        sub.unsubscribe()
        doSomething()
    })
```

Is there a way to unsubscribe without calling `unsubscribe()` from an outside subscription? For instance, is there some sort of operator I can use?

Comment: Maybe using the first() operator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to take one and unsubscribe

```
events
.pipe(filter(data => data === MessageType.INIT), take(1))
.subscribe(() => {
    doSomething()
})
```

So take(1) will take 1 subscription and unsubscribe

Or as was mentioned in comment by @Elias Soares you can use first

```
events
.pipe(first(data => data === MessageType.INIT))
.subscribe(() => {
    doSomething()
})
```